# Retrieve lost data from log file?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have an asp.net/vb file that receives data and processes it via a stored procedure.  The code had the width set to 2 for the year's varchar, so it was chopped, leaving only the first two digits to get inserted into the db.

Is this info possibly retrievable from a system/IIS log file or is it lost forever?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That data is lost forever.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have data that isn't corrupted?  Are the records in the database sequential or do they have automatically incrementing fields.  Do you have timestamps on the records?  Do the years correspond to the date when the record was inserted/updated?  Depending on your answers to these you **may** be able to reconstruct the data.  In particular using timestamps and/or autoincrement fields may give you the ability to determine a particular ordering between records.  If the date field is related to this ordering you may be able to infer the year from the data in other records.  It's very unlikely that any log files would be of any use.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the year was part of a querystring or URL...which is unlikely, at best. If your IIS admin happened to turn on logging of POST fields, then you may be able to retrieve it from there. Very few sites that I know of, though, ever log POST data.